# PhoneGap Build: is it possible to use PhoneGap SDK without Xcode to get UDID, pre-populate SMS messages, or integrate with Urban Airship?

Tags: iphone, html, ios4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Because PhoneGap now offers PhoneGap Build, a way to compile iPhone apps without Xcode, we're wondering if there's also a way to access the SDK without Xcode?

In particular, we need PhoneGap to allow our HTML5 app to access a device's UDID, to pre-populate a SMS message, and to integrate with Urban Airship for push notifications.

We want to convert our HTML5 app into a native iPhone app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if it's part of the JS wrapped PhoneGap SDK then yes you have access to some limited subset of the native SDK calls, and can use Build to do whatever's supported.

As for the UDID, while it's been deprecated in iOS5, it is supported through PhoneGap:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid

For SMS, you would have to build your project with XCode to include the SMS plugin, as it's not part of the default PhoneGap SDK any longer (used to be, don't know when it got dropped).
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer

Local notifications are supported well but I'm pretty sure you would also have to build in some additional code and build with XCode to get push notifications supported.

Apparently they are working plugins into the Build pipeline but last I checked it wasn't ready yet.

Comment: I am actually in the middle of conversation with 2 different people from phonegap today regarding custom plug in and phonegap build.  One of them said its supported and the other said not supported.  They gave me their answers in the same day.  I'm trying to get confirmation.

Comment: Thanks, atbebtg ... pls update when you hear one way or another. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming it is supported, how could you access the functionality without Xcode?